# SQL custom limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a calendar application, so I have a table called events with the columns title and startDate. The thing is I want to select the events that are occuring during and after a specified date.

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE startDate >= date
ORDER BY startDate ASC, title ASC
```

That's the easy part. Now to the harder part. I want to make a limit to just select the 7 first dates that have events on it. How do I do that?

Comment: It depends on which database you are querying. Some systems support the `LIMIT NumberOfRows` syntax at the end of the query.

Comment: @ba__friend: No you missunderstood the questions I want dates not rows. If it was just numberOfRows it would be super easy

Comment: Select only the Date column, but then you still have to use the `LIMIT` keyword to limit the number of **results** returned. See Aziz Shaikh answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT *
    FROM events
    WHERE startDate IN (select distinct startdate from events order by startdate desc limit 0,7)
   AND startDate >= date
    ORDER BY startDate ASC, title AS
```

Comment: This answer seems correct except you need the where clause `startDate >= date`. But I think I can do that on my own

Comment: Check also if some date filter is needed in the subquery. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Use [limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE startDate >= date
ORDER BY startDate ASC, title ASC
LIMIT 0,7
```

If you want just to retrive the first 7 dates:

```
SELECT distinct startDate
FROM events
WHERE startDate >= date
ORDER BY startDate
LIMIT 0,7
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think that this will only select the first 7 rows not 7 first dates of events

Comment: @Woho87: which selects? The second one will give you the first 7 distinct dates.